# software-properties-gtk is throwing python3-related exception

Tags: python, software-center, gtk, python3

Recently I started having a problem with my software update GUI tool in 16.04 - I've then tried to run `software-properties-gtk` as it seemed to me as Python related issue. I'm a Python programmer so I do some juggling with modules every now and then and I believe that somehow caused the issue here.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 34, in <module>
    from aptdaemon import client
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject, GLib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Clearly indicates that Ubuntu is trying to run a Python 2 program with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

The issue was with gi module installed for Python3. For some reason it could not be installed alongside with python2's gi.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall gi
```

Thanks for anyone who viewed this and wanted to help.